# Vue select option not returned same as value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

As I mentioned above, i use change function in Vue to retrieve value from model, but it doesn't same as the value.

---

This is Select tag

```
<b-form-select v-model="selectedLevel" @change="levelChange($event)" v-if="isProvinsiSelected === true">
  <option v-for="level in levels" :value="level.value" :key="level.value"> {{ level.text }}</option>
</b-form-select>
```

selectedLevel and levels

```
data () {
  return {
    selectedLevel: null,
    levels: [
      { text: 'Pilih level', value: null },
      { text: 'Provinsi', value: 1 },
      { text: 'Kabupaten', value: 2 },
      { text: 'Kecamatan', value: 3 },
      { text: 'Kelurahan', value: 4 }
    ],
  }
```

and the methods

```
levelChange: function (event) {
  console.log(this.selectedLevel)
  if (this.selectedLevel === 1) {
    this.isProvinsiSelected = true
  }
}
```

---

But when I trying to choose *'Pilih Level'*, the *this.selectedLevel* returns *Pilih level*, not *null*. And when I trying to choose *'Provinsi'*, the *this.selectedLevel* returns null, and when i choose *'Kabupaten'*, *this.selectedLevel* returns 1. Any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure why you're seeing this - I just copied your code into JSFiddle and it works perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/Ld924aqc/3/

Comment: Please add JSFiddle of what you are trying to do.